# How can I use public transportation to get around in Boliva?

Tags: public-transport, trekking, bolivia, la-paz

I'm planning a trip from La Paz to Patamanta first, then to Tuni, probably will stay the night in Tuni.

I'm not planning the multiple day trekking in Condoriri, but the Laguna Tuni looks amazing.

I prefer not to take a tour from La Paz because, after Tuni, I decided to go to Lake Titikaka. From Tuni, I think it's faster to go back to Patamamta, then to Copacabana.

The question is:

Are there regular buses from La Paz to Patamanta. There are a lot of buses from La Paz to Cobacabana, will they stop in Patamanta? From Patamanta can I find a taxi to Tuni?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you've asked four separate questions, they're all related: how to get around in Bolivia. Bolivia is fabulously varied, with its rainforest, desert, and mountains. However, the country's rugged terrain and poor transportation infrastructure present challenges of getting around on the whole. So, here are suggestions on resources that you may find more helpful than asking your questions piecemeal.

As you look for ways to travel around the country, you might start with [Rome2Rio](http://rome2rio.com): when no public transportation shows up in the search results, very likely it isn't a option. Move on to other alternatives.

There are also great guides with a wealth of information:

The always reliable [Rough Guides](https://www.roughguides.com/destinations/south-america/bolivia/getting-around/) offers this summary:

> Bolivia’s topography, size and lack of basic infrastructure means that getting around is often a challenge. The majority of Bolivia’s road network is unpaved, and most main roads are in a poor condition. However, travelling through the country’s varied and stunning landscapes is also one of the most enjoyable aspects of a visit to Bolivia, and the pleasure of many places lies as much in the getting there as in the destination itself.
>
> Most Bolivians travel by bus, as these go pretty much everywhere and are extremely good value. When there are no buses, they often travel on camiones (lorries), which are slower, much less comfortable and only slightly cheaper, but often go to places no other transport reaches. The much-reduced train network covers only a small fraction of the country, but offers a generally more comfortable and sedate (though not necessarily faster or more reliable) service. In parts of the Amazon lowlands river boats are still the main means of getting around.

[Lonely Planet](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/bolivia/transport/getting-around/local-transport) gives additional insight into local transport and some adventurous possibilities:

> **Camión**
>
> Prior to today's expansive bus network, camiónes (trucks) were often the only way for travelers to venture off the beaten track. These days, in the more populated areas you might consider a camión trip more for the novelty value than necessity; it is how many campesinos (subsistence farmers) choose to travel.
>
> Camiones generally cost about half of the bus fare. You’ll need time and a strong constitution, as travel can be excruciatingly slow and rough, depending on the cargo and number of passengers. A major plus is the raw experience, including the best views of the countryside.
>
> On any camión trip, especially in the highlands by day or night, be sure to take plenty of warm clothing as night temperatures can plunge below freezing and at best they can be chilly.
>
> To get on a camión, wait on the side of the road and flag it down as it passes.
>
> **Micros, Minibuses & Trufis**
>
> Micros (half-size buses) are used in larger cities and are Bolivia’s least expensive form of public transport. They follow set routes, with the route numbers or letters usually marked on a placard behind the windshield. There is also often a description of the route, including the streets taken to reach the end of the line. They can be hailed anywhere along their route, though bus stops are starting to pop up in some bigger cities. When you want to disembark, move toward the front and tell the driver or assistant where you want them to stop.
>
> Minibuses and trufis (which may be cars, vans or minibuses), also known as rapiditos or colectivos, are prevalent in larger towns and cities, and follow set routes that are numbered and described on placards. They are always cheaper than taxis and nearly as convenient if you can get the hang of them. As with micros, you can board or alight anywhere along their route.

And, as shared in response to your earlier question, expats Brig and Dan [Bolivian Life](https://www.bolivianlife.com/transportation-in-bolivia/) offer first-hand tips on getting around the country:

> An adventure in itself, navigating Bolivia’s rugged topography can leave even professional travelers reeling.
>   Public transport throughout the country, while generally safe, can be tricky and unreliable, not to mention eventful. Because timetables in Bolivia aren’t available online and many bus terminal staff don’t speak English, acquiring information on how to reach your next destination can be difficult. Departure and arrival times change without notice and ticket prices don’t always reflect quality.
>
> Also, many of Bolivia’s roads are still unpaved, making traveling between cities, long, tumultuous and bumpy. It’s not unusual for ground transportation to be delayed by protests leaving travelers stranded for days on end. The unpredictable rainy season can also impact the best-laid travel plans, especially in the eastern plains of Bolivia where roads are known to get washed out.
>
> Despite these inconveniences, there are many positives to traveling by local transportation in Bolivia. Firstly, travel is incredibly cheap and unlike most western countries, taking a taxi is a completely affordable option. Secondly, taking the bus is a great way to experience Bolivia’s unique landscapes. Being forced to sit back and soak in awe-inspiring views for hours on end is a true blessing in disguise. Finally, traveling by public transport allows you to experience the friendliness of the Bolivian people. It’s very common for locals to smile and say “buen dia” when boarding the bus; a refreshing custom in a manic world.

Tener una gran aventura en la magnífica Bolivia !